# Burninate 'arrayslice' and retag 'array-slice' ( -> 'slice')

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-synonym-process

['array-slice' is a synonym for slice](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slice/info), which I guess was the consensus decision (even though array-slicing has more nuances than 1D slicing, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858377/whats-the-difference-between-np-array-0-and-np-array-0)). But whatever, I guess that alias is a settled decision.

My question is: separately, **someone created ['arrayslice'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayslice)**. Should we burninate it and retag those 4 questions as 'array-slice'?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes, we should.**

Those are only 4 questions, the tag has no individual meaning that [array-slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-slice) wouldn't solve (it's the same name, after all) and the combined views are around 300. Someone with full editing privileges could do this in around 2 minutes, so let's just wait.

Comment: Retagging done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922726/how-to-convert-swift-arrayslice-to-swift-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235968/swift-arrayslice-lazy-recursive-function-running-out-of-memory are referring to swift's [ArraySlice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice) which may eventually need its own tag.